# Why does my app crash when I tap the background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, selector

When the app goes into an alert state and I press the background image I get the following error message.

```
2015-04-04 01:06:39.583 APP[479:44057] -[__NSCFString resignFirstResponder]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16d627c0
2015-04-04 01:06:39.584 APP[479:44057] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString resignFirstResponder]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16d627c0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x270e35a7 0x34cc9c77 0x270e8a6d 0x270e6949 0x27017b68 0x4ed91 0x2a76507f 0x2a6139ed 0x2aa29951 0x2a5dd3c5 0x2a5db33f 0x2a611ddd 0x2a6116ad 0x2a5e7fbd 0x2a85bbb5 0x2a5e6a07 0x270aa237 0x270a964b 0x270a7cc9 0x26ff4b51 0x26ff4963 0x2e5331a9 0x2a646c91 0x4ca35 0x35272aaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Normally this screen does not have the error, it just happens after I set an alarm state for the app. The app uses this method to dismiss the keyboard on some of the views in the storyboard.

```
-(void)dismissKeyboard { 
[message resignFirstResponder]; 
[contact1 resignFirstResponder]; 
[contact2 resignFirstResponder]; 
[contact3 resignFirstResponder]; 
}
```

Comment: The code you have shown is unrelated to the crash you have received.  The exception tells you that a `resignFirstResponder` message was sent to an instance of `NSCFString` - my guess is that you have assigned a string to your background image instead of a UIImage from the string or something like that.  You should show the code where you set the background

Comment: Did you go `[self.myTextView resignFirstResponder];` or did you go `[self.myTextView.text resignFirstResponder];` ?  Tab fail maybe ? :P

Comment: @Zhang I did not put and resign in there. Maybe I should?

Comment: Does adding a global exception breakpoint help nail it down to where it is about to crash ?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Is there an example I can follow?

Comment: In Xcode > Left hand side pane, click on the second icon from the right to open breakpoint navigator. Then click on the bottom left plus sign and choose Add Exception Breakpoint. That's it.

Comment: Right, I thought you meant a method to handle the exception. I did put a few breakpoints in there previously. I'm not sure where the best place to check is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74480/discussion-between-jack-shultz-and-zhang).

Comment: Try turning on zombies in the diagnostics part of your build scheme.  There's a good chance that something has been released and had its address re-used to store a string.

Comment: @Zhang gave me a solution in the chat. I'm going to let him post that so he can get some points.

Comment: Please improve your question with any pertinent information that was discussed and uncovered in chat so that the question will help future visitors. Doing this will help improve the quality of this site, and may help change your question's down votes into up-votes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the chat with Jack, it appears the culprit of the crash was due to a method:

```
-(void)dismissKeyboard
{
    // ------------------------------------------------------
    // These variables appear to be NSString, so it crashes
    // ------------------------------------------------------
    [message resignFirstResponder];
    [contact1 resignFirstResponder];
    [contact2 resignFirstResponder];
    [contact3 resignFirstResponder];
}
```

So the solution was to simply change it to:

```
-(void)dismissKeyboard
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```